How to create NSImage and display it in SwiftUI view on MacOS?
How to create NSImage and display it in SwiftUI view on MacOS?
According to How can i update swift variable when c++ callback function triggered,
I can send frame count from c++ video callback function to the text in the SwiftUI view on MacOS, and display it.
Now I try to send RGB raw data and RGB raw data size to SwiftUI view and display it on MacOS, but I don't know how to do it after trying.
My Xcode version is 15.2.
My MacOS version is Mac mini, MacOS M1 64bit, Sonoma 14.6.1.
My code is below,

In MyCLibrary.h

typedef void callback_t1(uint8_t* rgbBufferPtr, uint32_t rgbBufferBytes);
callback_t1* callback1 = NULL;


In CWrapperBridging.h

void setCallBack1(callback_t1 _callback1);


In CWrapper.cpp

std::vector<uint8_t> vctFrameData

extern "C" void setCallBack1(callback_t1 _callback1)
{
    callback1 = _callback1;
}

extern "C" void videoCallbackFunction(void* RGBbufferPtr, uint32_t RGBbufferBytes)
{
    int sz = (int)vctFrameData.size();

        if(sz != (int)RGBbufferBytes)
        {
            vctFrameData.resize(RGBbufferBytes);
            std::cout << "*** vctFrameData is resized @ videoCallbackFunction()" << std::endl;
        }

    std::memcpy(&vctFrameData[0], RGBbufferPtr, RGBbufferBytes);

    uint8_t* buffer_ptr = &vctFrameData[0]; 

    if(callback1)
            callback1(buffer_ptr, RGBbufferBytes);
}



In MyCLibraryInterface.swift

import Foundation
import AppKit

class MyCLibraryInterface: ObservableObject {
    @Published var nsimage: NSImage
    
    static let shared = MyCLibraryInterface()
    
    init() {
        setCallBack1 { 
            let newNsImage = ??? // I don't know how to do it.
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                MyCLibraryInterface.shared.nsimage = newNsImage as NSImage
            }
        }
    }
}



In ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myCLibInterface: MyCLibraryInterface = MyCLibraryInterface.shared
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Image(myCLibInterface.nsimage) // ??? Here, I get <Missing argument label 'nsImage:' in call> error message. How can I solve it?
                .frame(width: 640.0, height: 480.0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
 }

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


My question is,

How can I create NSImage in init() in class MyCLibraryInterface when
calling setCallBack1?
Image(myCLibInterface.nsimage), I get <Missing argument label
'nsImage:' in call> error message, how can I solve it?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

As I mentioned before, for (2) do what the error message is saying, use Image(nsImage: myCLibInterface.nsimage)

@workingdog support Ukraine, Thank you.

Note, you should be using @StateObject var myCLibInterface = MyCLibraryInterface() and there is no need for it to be a singleton, remove the static let shared = MyCLibraryInterface()

@workingdog support Ukraine, got it, thanks a lot. Have a nice day.

@workingdog support Ukraine, after I do it as you mentioned, I get <unknown attribute 'StateObject'> error message. May I know how I can solve it? Thanks for help. Have a nice day.

what I mean is in ContentView replace @ObservedObject var myCLibInterface:.... with @StateObject var myCLibInterface = MyCLibraryInterface() and remove the static let shared = MyCLibraryInterface() in your class MyCLibraryInterface.

@workingdog support Ukraine, thanks for help. Have a nice day.
